# Add padding to a TextObj item in a ZedGraph chart

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Is it possible to add padding to a TextObj? I am looking to display a value on the chart, with a visible border, but the text is always too close to the border. Is it possible to extend the height/width of the box to always leave some space/padding?

I have tried updating the height/width of the box, but this doesn't appear to have any effect. I have also used empty string spaces and while this works on the left-hand side, it has no effect on the right side.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Any suggestions on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GraphPane myPane;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        AddTxtObject();
    }

    private void AddTxtObject()
    {
        TextObj txtObj = new TextObj("ZedGraph Version 5.1.5.xxx", 0.7, 0.8, CoordType.PaneFraction, AlignH.Left, AlignV.Bottom);

        txtObj.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        txtObj.FontSpec.Size = 10;
        txtObj.FontSpec.Fill.Color = Color.Black;

        txtObj.FontSpec.Border.Color = Color.Black;
        txtObj.FontSpec.Border.Width = 25.0f;

        myPane.GraphObjList.Add(txtObj);
        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();

    }
}
```

By changing font size & the border width, you may achieve padding effect with Zedgraph.

[image]